# PHP - DB2 license file location

Tags: php, db2-zos

I'm running an XAMPP server for my PHP app and I would like to connect to a zOS DB2 table. I receive license error. I can connect a non-zOS DB2 DB so DB2 functions work. The error message I receive is:

> An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598

My license file is `db2consv.lic`

Where do I have to copy this lic to take effect?

Comment: If you want a different title, edit the title.

Comment: Thx, I found it.. !

Comment: You always have the rights to edit your own question.